# Access parent object of Button in click event in UWP application with C#

Tags: c#, oop, button, uwp

This is for a UWP application for raspberry pi (c#). I have a button as a public member of a class written by me. Since this is a member of class. Whenever an object of this class is created, it needs to have a Click event. I need to have the click event inside the MainPage.xaml.cs file in order for it to have access to other functions, instead of the actual class.

I am able to use the following code:

```
ExecutionSequence newSeq = new ExecutionSequence();
newSeq.SelectionButton.Click += SelectionButton_Click;



private void SelectionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button tempbutton = sender as Button;
}
```

The above code gives full access of the properties of the Button.

However, I am looking for help in the above scenario to access the actual object of class to which this button belongs to as the event requires to access other members of class.

Please note that I considered making the click event as another member of the class itself. But it makes things complex in my case.

Comment: Could you share `ExecutionSequence` code, and how do you render `ExecutionSequence` in your page?

Comment: And have you checked FrameworkElement  [`Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.parent?view=winrt-19041) property that  use to get the element's parent.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT OP appears to be asking about container class, not XAML parent. You'll need to have something (say the Tag) that lets you get from the Button back to the containing class. You have to do this yourself somehow, because an object could be part of multiple containing classes.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I agree your comments, I will a solution about how to tag to find the specific control for op.

Comment: Another option is to put the extra data in the delegate: `newSeq.SelectionButton.Click += (s,e) => SelectionButton_Click(s, e, newSeq);`

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for your help. This will certainly solve the problem and is exactly what I am looking for. However, your code gives an error at (s,e). "A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Comment: Then use a different parameter name. One that doesn't conflict with any other local variables or parameter names.